# Detect the green lines in this image and calculate their lengths

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, rgb, hsv

[image]Sample Images

[image]

The image can be more noisy at times where more objects intervene from the background. Right now I am using various techniques using the RGB colour space to detect the lines but it fails when there is change in the colour due to intervening obstacles from the background. I am using opencv and python.
I have read that HSV is better for colour detection and used but haven't been successful yet.
I am not able to find a generic solution to this problem. Any hints or clues in this direction would be of great help.

Comment: I am currently working a code for your problem. can you provide another image?. These image is super duper noisy. Even when noise removal filters are applied there is still a lot of noise.

Comment: Actually the image can be more noisy. If you want I can you provide you more images. By the way I noticed an interesting thing, the lines are removed when I increase the saturation value beyond a certain value(this value is different in different images) but the noisy remains. May be that's something to work upon !!!

Comment: Look, I will be posting a workflow for your today. If it is possible to provide you with a code, I will. But if I haven't finished the code, I will post it later.

Comment: Do you want to detect the skinny diagonal line as well, or do you only want to detect the 4 fatter lines? Will the line orientation always be horizontal or can it be in any configuration? When you say you want to detect the lines, what do you want to detect about them? Length? Width? Angle? Position? Total number?

Comment: I want to detect the 4 fatter lines. The orientation would generally be horizontal although they can be a bit oblique at times. I want to calculate line's width and the perpendicular distance b/w them.

Comment: Please summarise everything you know about these mysterious lines - are there always 4? Will they all be the same length? Will they be parallel or nearly so? What else might be in the image? Do you know what percentage of the image width they should fill? How far off horizontal might they be?

Comment: @Mark: "Mysterious lines" !!!. The lines to be detected can be 2 or 4. They will be nearly horizontal and almost parallel. They will be of varying lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the fact that you know you are trying to detect a line by using the line hough transform.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

- When the obstacle also look like a line use the fact that you know approximately what is the orientation of the green lines.
- If you don't know the orientation of the line use hte fact that there are several green lines with the same orientation and only one line that is the obstacle

Here is a code for what i meant:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Params
minLineCount = 300 # min number of point alogn line with the a specif orientation
minArea = 100

# Read img
img = cv2.imread('i.png')
greenChannel = img[:,:,1]

# Do noise reduction
iFilter = cv2.bilateralFilter(greenChannel,5,5,5)

# Threshold data
#ret,iThresh = cv2.threshold(iFilter,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
iThresh = (greenChannel > 4).astype(np.uint8)*255

# Remove small areas
se1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
iThreshRemove = cv2.morphologyEx(iThresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, se1)

# Find edges
iEdge = cv2.Canny(iThreshRemove,50,100)

# Hough line transform
lines = cv2.HoughLines(iEdge, 1, 3.14/180,75)

# Find the theta with the most lines
thetaCounter = dict()
for line in lines:
    theta = line[0, 1]
    if theta in thetaCounter:
        thetaCounter[theta] += 1
    else:
        thetaCounter[theta] = 1

maxThetaCount = 0
maxTheta = 0
for theta in thetaCounter:
    if thetaCounter[theta] > maxThetaCount:
        maxThetaCount = thetaCounter[theta]
        maxTheta = theta

# Find the rhos that corresponds to max theta
rhoValues = []
for line in lines:
    rho = line[0, 0]
    theta = line[0, 1]
    if theta == maxTheta:
        rhoValues.append(rho)

# Go over all the lines with the specific orientation and count the number of pixels on that line
# if the number is bigger than minLineCount draw the pixels in finaImage
lineImage = np.zeros_like(iThresh, np.uint8)
for rho in range(min(rhoValues), max(rhoValues), 1):
    a = np.cos(maxTheta)
    b = np.sin(maxTheta)
    x0 = round(a*rho)
    y0 = round(b*rho)
    lineCount = 0
    pixelList = []
    for jump in range(-1000, 1000, 1):
        x1 = int(x0 + jump * (-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + jump * (a))
        if x1 < 0 or y1 < 0 or x1 >= lineImage.shape[1] or y1 >= lineImage.shape[0]:
            continue
        if iThreshRemove[y1, x1] == int(255):
            pixelList.append((y1, x1))
            lineCount += 1

    if lineCount > minLineCount:
        for y,x in pixelList:
            lineImage[y, x] = int(255)

# Remove small areas

## Opencv 2.4
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(lineImage,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE )

finalImage = np.zeros_like(lineImage)
finalShapes = []
for contour in contours:
    if contour.size > minArea:
        finalShapes.append(contour)

cv2.fillPoly(finalImage, finalShapes, 255)
## Opencv 3.0
# output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(lineImage, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
#
# finalImage = np.zeros_like(output[1])
# finalImage = output[1]
# stat = output[2]
# for label in range(output[0]):
#     if label == 0:
#         continue
#     cc = stat[label,:]
#     if cc[cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] < minArea:
#         finalImage[finalImage == label] = 0
#     else:
#         finalImage[finalImage == label] = 255

# Show image
#cv2.imwrite('finalImage2.jpg',finalImage)
cv2.imshow('a', finalImage.astype(np.uint8))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and the result for the images:
[image: Result]

[image]

Comment: You're using OTSU threshing before identifying the lines. The lines get removed if the intensity of the line is lesser than the OTSU thresh value. This workflow worked on this image but doesn't work on most of other samples.

Comment: i replaced the OTSU threshold with basic threholding like iThresh = (greenChannel > 10).astype(np.uint8)*255 and it still worked. Please post another hard image and let me see where are the problems

Comment: Just saw that you added another example i will fix my code accordingly

Comment: I changed the code to use a simple threshold and some more cleaning up in the end.

Comment: I was using opencv 2.4.9. Your code probably uses 3.0. Won't it create other issues with the code?

Comment: I don't know. Are there any function that i used that are only available for opencv 3?

Comment: Yes, connectedComponentsWithStats

Comment: The reason i do the last part with connectedComponentsWithStats  is to eliminate small areas. You can try to implement it in opencv 2.4.9 using findContours and the area calculation using contourArea. If you are willing to use another library like skimage you can use skimage.measure.label and than skimage.measure.regionprops to get the area

Comment: I tried running your code. The lineImage turns out be completely black in all the samples and hence no contours are detected using the function findContour.

Comment: Edit the code to work with opencv 2.4 using findContour. On my side it  works well.

Comment: I don't know how but this code doesn't work on my system. The lineImage is completely black every time and no contours are detected in it.

Answer (score 1):

**STILL IN PROGRESS**

First of all, an RGB image consists of 3 grayscale images. Since you need the green color you will deal only with one channel. The green one. To do so, you can split the image, you can use `b,g,r = cv2.split('Your Image')`. You will get an output like that if you are showing the green channel:

[image: green_channel]

After that you should threshold the image using your desired way. I prefer `Otsu's thresholding` in this case. The output after thresholding is:

[image: thresholded_image]

It's obvious that the thresholded image is extremley noisy. So performing `erosion` will reduce the noise a little bit. The noise reduced image will be similar to the following:

[image: erosion]

I tried using `closing` instead of `dilation`, but `closing` preserves some unwanted noise. So I separately performed `erosion` followed by `dilation`. After `dilation` the output is:

[image: dilation]

**Note that:** *You can do your own way in morphological operation. You can use `opening` instead of what I did. The results are subjective from
one person to another.*

Now you can try one these two methods:

**1. Blob Detection.**
 **2. HoughLine Transform.**

**TODO**

*Try out these two methods and choose the best.*

Comment: Thanks Osama. I have tried these techniques but have had very little success with it. If you only consider only the green part, the algorithm can detect green things from the background. By the way, did you consider the point that I made about saturation in an earlier comment.

Comment: @Abhyudai Excuse me, I don't get your comment. I don't understand it very well. I operated on the image in the rgb colorspace as it's okay. You can also convert it to hsv which will be something good. But for me in rgb it worked so why change the colorspace. I have a question, does my answer help or not. Did you try it out so far. I will complete the answer when finished.

Comment: Don't you think an object in the background (of colour yellow(R + G)) is likely to hamper your workflow if you use only green colour-space? Your answer wasn't helpful as I have used these techniques before posting this question. The solution might work on some images, but I am not able to find a generic one. I can provide you more samples if you want.

Comment: @Abhyudai okay provide me with another sample. Try to make it clear in your question and state what you already performed. My work is still in progress because I want to make a generic code as you say but it will be a hard objective to achieve at the moment.

Comment: I have used morphological transformations, otsu threshing, houghLines Transform, edge detection, simple colour masking, blob detection

Comment: I do not exactly want the code but you can share an idea or clue if it works.

Comment: @Abhyudai what else do you think is possible to do?, you have mentioned roughly everything possible. HL Transform, Edge detection, simple color masking, and blob detection. I think you should have got a good result from one of these. Unless you want something else rather than detecting only green color and calculating their lengths.